# Setup Failed Fatal Error during installation (0x80070643) SSIS Projects

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I installed Microsoft visual studio 2019 and wanted to add the SSIS extension but got the following error.

> Microsoft AS OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002.

[image]

Here is [the error log](https://www.mediafire.com/file/8vori6k2w26f1ir/Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220223154828.log/file). And the following is the section where the exception was thrown:

```
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:37]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft AS OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016 (id: SSAS_OLEDB2016)
[2410:2414][2022-02-23T15:59:37]i301: Applying execute package: SSAS_OLEDB2016, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C49E181B-C19F-4A1F-BE76-D463E7E3B2B5}v13.1.4561.14\payload\SQL_AS_OLEDB2016.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 15, Overall progress: 78
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 27, Overall progress: 79
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 40, Overall progress: 80
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 53, Overall progress: 81
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 66, Overall progress: 82
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:38]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 79, Overall progress: 83
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T15:59:40]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 92, Overall progress: 84
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T16:00:00]e000: BootstrapperEngineDataModel.OnError: Burn engine encountered error. PackageId: SSAS_OLEDB2016, ErrorType: WindowsInstaller, ErrorCode: 1935, Data: 1935,{98CB24AD-52FB-DB5F-A01F-C8B3B9A1E18E},0x80070002,IAssemblyCacheItem,Commit,Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86", ErrorMessage: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002. , UIHint: 0
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T16:00:00]i000: MainViewModel.AddFailedCondition: Error: Microsoft AS OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002. 
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T16:00:00]e000: MainViewModel.OnPackageError: setup failed for packageId: SSAS_OLEDB2016, package: Microsoft AS OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016, errorCode: 1935, errorMessage: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070002. 
[2410:2414][2022-02-23T16:00:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[2410:2414][2022-02-23T16:00:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0AB0:0774][2022-02-23T16:00:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
```

can anyone explain where the error is and how to fix it?

Comment: provide the log information. what is the error

Comment: @VenkataramanR please check error log https://www.mediafire.com/file/8vori6k2w26f1ir/Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20220223154828.log/file

Comment: What is the SQL Server version installed on that machine? The .NET framework? Windows version? Operating system architecture (x32 or x64)?

Comment: @Hadi SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition, Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1, Microsoft .NET SDK 5.0.405 (x64) from Visual Studio, Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19042)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the latest .NET products are installed from the Windows Feature.

[image]

Then install the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)